# How can I check variable php in a better way?

Tags: php

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    $rep_pass = $_POST['rep-password'];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $surname = $_POST['surename'];
    $phonenr = $_POST['phone-nr'];
    $place = $_POST['place'];    
}

if ($email != "" && $username != "" && $pass != "" && $rep_pass != "" &&  $firstname != "" && $surname != "" && $phonenr != "" && $place != "") { 

}
```

Is there a shorter way to do the same as what I'm doing in the condition of the second  `if` statement?

Comment: Well, is making the if sentence shorter the only requirement? because if so you could make the variables into an' array, and before the IF sentence you could run them through a foreach and set another variable to FALSE/true if one isn't set.

Comment: The only thing I could think of is iterating through the `$_POST` array.

Comment: foreach ($_POST as $val) { if (!empty($val) { /* do this */ } else { /* do that */ } ) } this is the most simple way in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$required = ['email', 'username', 'password', ...];
foreach($required as $field)
  if(empty($_POST[$field]))
    throw new EpicFailureException("Mandatory field '$field' is empty");
```

Comment: ++ Beat me in your speed, elegant solution as well.

Comment: Rofl EpicFailureException. Thanks this is what I needed! :D

Comment: I would still add an isset validation.

Comment: Be careful with zero '0' because empty function return true.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a preset accepted postvars thing.
You can add custom error messages during validation and such, and my code auto instantiates your variables. Only thing is I don't account for the dashes, but you could consider removing those from your form name's.

```
 $accepted = array('register','email','username','password','rep-password','firstname','surename','phone-nr','place');
$_POST = array('register'=>'blah','email'=>'blah','username'=>'blah','password'=>'blah','rep-password'=>'blah','firstname'=>'blah','surename'=>'blah','phone-nr'=>'blah','place'=>'blah');
$proper = true;
$erroron = "";
foreach($accepted as $val) {
    if(isset($_POST[$val])) {
        trim($_POST[$val]);
        if(!empty($_POST[$val])) {
            $$val = $_POST[$val];
        }
        else {
            $proper=false;
            $erroron = "Error occured on $val which is empty";
            break;
        }

    }
    else {
        $proper = false;
        $erroron = "Error occured on $val which is not defined";
        break;
    }
}
if($proper) {
echo "email = $email, you might want to consider removing dashes from form names to auto instantiate those variables";
}
else {
    echo "Not everything was done properly. The error message is: $erroron";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your values into an array and then use the built in function `array_filter()`.
If you don't provide a callback function to `array_filter()` it will only remove the false or empty value of your array. 
Then count the value before and after the modification if they are != a value is missing.

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $user['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    $user['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $user['pass'] = $_POST['password'];
    $user['rep_pass'] = $_POST['rep-password'];
    $user['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname'];
    $user['surname'] = $_POST['surename'];
    $user['phonenr'] = $_POST['phone-nr'];
    $user['place'] = $_POST['place'];

}

$nbArg = count($user);
if($nbArg != count(array_filter($user))) {
echo "One Value is missing"
}
```